# how do you compute the channel gain from path loss index in wireless communication?

Tags: signal-analysis

how do you compute the channel gain from path loss index in wireless communication?

Comment: Welcome to DSP.SE! Please try to expand on your question. For example: Can you define what the path loss index is? Googling the phrase turns up a first return of the Path Loss Wikipedia page... which does not refer to the path loss index.  What sort of wireless comms are you interested in? e.g. What frequencies? Microwave? VHF? Something else?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will have to properly define *path loss index*. As soon as you have done that, you'll have a formula that links path loss index and attenuation/gain.